# Can an Outsider called via a Planar Binding spell use an Anti-Magic Field to escape a diagram created by Magic Circle?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, monsters

A friend and I were discussing whether or not an Anti-Magic Field would cancel a diagram created by a Magic Circle. My argument is that it would not due to this line in the text for diagram

> A creature cannot use its spell resistance against a magic circle
>   prepared with a diagram, and none of its abilities or attacks can
>   cross the diagram.

Since this effect is magical, would anti-magic field cancel it out?

Answer (score 16):

## Very few outsiders can even create an [*antimagic field*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/antimagic-field/)…

Were this player's PC to be using spells like [*lesser planar binding*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/planar-binding/) to bring forth creatures, fretting that the called creatures might use an effect like the spell [*antimagic field*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/antimagic-field/) would be the least of his PC's worries.

That is, even were his PC to have done *very* little research, chances are the called creature simply *can't* employ an effect like the spell *antimagic field*. In official, traditional *Pathfinder* there seems to be only one creature within the *binding* spells' limits that possesses such an ability: the [movanic deva](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/angel/angel-movanic-deva/), and it's pretty much just a handsome dude with a sword if it uses its 1/day spell-like ability *antimagic field* in a room with a low ceiling.

All the *other* outsiders that can cast or use an ability like the spell *antimagic field* are well beyond the Hit Dice limit of the typical caster's *binding* spells: for example, the [empyrean angel](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/angel/angel-empyrean/) (HD 25 and CR 20), the demon lord [Tsathogga](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/demon-lords/demon-lord-tsathogga-the-frog-god-tohc/) (HD 42 and CR 30), and [the Oinodaemon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/daemons/daemon-the-oinodaemon/) (HD 49 and CR 37) each prepare the spell, and the empyreal lords [Black Butterfly](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/empyreal-lord/empyreal-lord-black-butterfly/) (HD 33 and CR 28) and [Korda](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/empyreal-lord/empyreal-lord-korada/) (HD 32 and CR 26) can each 3/day use the spell-like ability. [Seriously, the bench just ain't that deep.](https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=006680642033474972217%3A6zo0hx_wle8&q=lesser%20planar%20binding#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=antimagic%20field%20outsider&gsc.sort=&gsc.ref=more%3Abestiary) In short, unless the caster's binding nontraditional outsiders that are themselves casters or one specific kind of angel, this won't be a thing, and it'll never come up.

Nonetheless, this player supposes that a GM *could* somewhat maliciously decide that his PC calls *via* a *binding* spell an outsider that just so happens to possess gear enabling it to use an effect like the spell *antimagic field*, like the [*equalizer shield*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-shields/equalizer-shield/) or a *scroll of antimagic field*. (Note that in this latter case, the GM likely must also customize the creature so that it possesses a sufficient Use Magic Device skill modifier to *employ* that scroll!)

### …*And* this GM agrees that an outsider can't use [*antimagic field*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/planar-binding/) to free itself from an inward-focused [*magic circle*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-circle-against-evil/)

This reader agrees with your assessment and would take this even further.

The *normal* yet inward-focused [*magic circle against evil*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-circle-against-evil/) description says, "The trapped creature can do nothing that disturbs the circle, directly or indirectly…." That would make this GM rule that an outsider called with a spell like [*lesser planar binding*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/planar-binding/) would be *disturbing the circle* were it to cast or use an effect like the spell [*antimagic field*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/antimagic-field/). This GM would rule that the magic of the *circle* spell simply forbids the trapped creature from casting the spell or using the ability just as the magic of the *circle* forbids the creature from doing anything else that can disturb the circle.

Likewise, because adding *special* diagrams to an inward-focused *magic circle* spell means *both* that "none of its [the trapped creature's] abilities or attacks can cross the diagram" *and* that the trapped "creature itself cannot disturb the diagram either directly or indirectly, as noted above," the *circle* effect is then *doubly* secure against any called creature's *antimagic field* spell or ability.

Comment: The list of outsiders that can cast AMF also includes Planetar and Tataka Rakshasa. It isn't on their typical spell loadout, but any given individual might have different spells prepared.

Comment: @topquark O, yeah, I'm sure there are other outsiders that *can* — but traditionally *don't* — cast the spell *antimagic field*, but then the GM is customizing those monsters (that specifically *cast spells*) so that they prepare *antimagic field* seemingly so that then there is *this question.* That seems a long way to go. However, if you think it'll improve the answer, I can include those as additional examples. (And, sincerely, thank you for those examples, by the way—searching for that is difficult.)

Comment: @topquark (O, I did hedge a little, by the way: I think *unless the caster's binding nontraditional outsiders that are themselves casters* may cover caster creatures like the planetar. And, having never before typed *planetar*, I now wonder if it's pronounced *plain-tar* or *plan-eh-tar*.)

Comment: There is a list of bindable outsiders on ultimate magic, but that list got outdated by bestiary 3 (i think). I believe the book of the damned has updated that list with the new evil outsiders, and I'm nearly sure that the summoner handbook has another updated list (but I gotta check my pdf again). Edit: Nope, it expands the summoning lists.

Comment: @HeyICanChan there is one bound Planetar in Rise of the Runelords, just to let you know. I believe the spell used was [Binding](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/binding/), even though the spell clearly states that antimagic can remove it (so we can only assume it works for story reasons or because it did work that way in 3.5).

Answer (score 8):

### No, it doesn't work.

The only ways to leave the trap are spelled by the [Planar Binding](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/planar-binding/) spell:

> The creature can escape from the trap by successfully pitting its Spell Resistance against your caster level check, by dimensional travel, or with a successful Charisma check.

Also, remind him that planar bound creatures are [called](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration), not summoned. As such, they are not merely a magical construct, but a real creature that has a name and can be permanently killed:

> The duration of a calling spell is instantaneous, which means that the called creature can’t be dispelled.

This also means that destroying the circle won't send it back either. Also, if you check the [Magic Circle](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-circle-against-evil/) spell, it also states the bound creature cannot disrupt a successful circle:

> The trapped creature can do nothing that disturbs the circle, directly or indirectly, but other creatures can.